# How to generate Text as Image within Listview ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have listview in which I want to generate my email data as image. Follwing is my code.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Imaging" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing.Drawing2D" %>

 <asp:ListView ID="lvtest" runat="server" 
      CellPadding="0" 
      RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
      GroupPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholdersp" 
      ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholdersp" >
      <LayoutTemplate>
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholdersp" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="accordionBg">                              
                <h3><%# Eval("UserName") %></h3>
                <h4>
                     <%# Eval("Designation").ToString() == "" ? "" : Eval("Designation") + "<br/>" %>
                     <%# Eval("Qualification").ToString() == "" ? "" : Eval("Qualification")+ "<br/>" %>

                     <%
                          Response.Clear();
                          int height = 100;
                          int width = 200;
                          Random r = new Random();
                          int x = r.Next(75);

                          Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                          Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

                          g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
                          g.Clear(Color.Orange);
                          g.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, 1, 1, width-3, height-3);
                          g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, 2, 2, width-3, height-3);
                          g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, width, height);
                          g.DrawString(Eval("Email").ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), 
                          SystemBrushes.WindowText, new PointF(x,50) );

                          bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                          g.Dispose();
                          bmp.Dispose();
                          Response.End();
                      %>
                </h4>

                <p class="clear"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion_content">
                <div class="vertical_accordion_content">
                    <p><%# Eval("Description")%></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

But it doesn't work.error occured as

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The error you described is not caused by your rendering code, but by the lack of a valid data source for your list view. I've simplified your code a little bit. It should cause the same error (if we are looking at the actual markup):

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvtest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h3><%# Eval("UserName") %></h3>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

You are trying to evaluate an `UserName` property but do not specify the source of it. You have to either specify a `DataSource` directly, or refer to a `DataSourceID`:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ListView ID="lvtest" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h3><%# Eval("UserName") %></h3>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Note that the above could doesn't do anything and will likely lead to other errors. For further details, you can refer to [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) or one of the may tutorials around the web.